# Out of bounds for list when index is in bounds windows forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

There is a strange error in my windows forms application, I get:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

at the code `byte listval = list1[i]`. The length of `list1` is 18, and in Autos it shows `list1[i]` to be the correct value, but in the code there is an error. Is this a code error or just a visual studio glitch?

```
static class Class1
{
    static List<byte> list1 = new List<byte>();
    public static void Start()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Process)) { IsBackground = true };
        t.Start();
    }
    static void Action()
    {
        byte[] array1;
        while(true) {
            while(list1.Count == 0) {}
            array1 = new byte[list1.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; ++i)
            {
                byte listval = list1[i];
                array1[i] = listval;
            }
        }
    }
    public static void Add(byte[] data)
    {
        list1.AddRange(data);
    }
}
```

Edit
It was fixed by changing byte listval = list1[i] to byte listval = list1.ToList()[i];

Comment: my money is on "code error"

Comment: The fact that this `Action()` will never stop executing is a good indication that it's likely code error.

Comment: I'm seeing this here `while(list1.Count == 0) {}`, and just trying to figure out why it's there (relatively). When pausing is totally valid.

Comment: while(true){ } - I'm feeling sick :(